# Why am I getting 550 permission error on ftp

Tags: ftp

Two laptops on my home network.  First laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. For this exercise this is my ftp server.

I have these directories of interest.  As you can see, directory /VMLab/VirtualBoxVMs has all permissions

```
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:/$ pwd
/
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:/$ ll|grep VM
drwxrwxrwx   8 ed   root  4096 Jan 23 13:47 VMLab/
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:/$ cd VMLab
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:/VMLab$ ll|grep VirtualBoxVM
drwxrwxrwx 10 ed   ed    4096 Mar 21 14:34 VirtualBoxVMs/
```

And here is the current IP address (DHCP assigned) Trust me, the masked parts of the IP address are consistent and correct.  And note that I am supplying the same user as the one who *owns* the directories in question.

```
ed@ed-Gazelle-00:/VMLab$ ifconfig wlp3s0
wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:a4:71:f2:0c:56  
          inet addr:***.***.*.113  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::10c1:595e:f940:87b2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:518647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:328184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:198985657 (198.9 MB)  TX bytes:162426683 (162.4 MB)
```

Now, on my other laptop, Windows 10, I can successfully establish an ftp connection to that IP, change directories to that directory, but when I actually try to 'put' a file, I get 'permission denied'

```
C:\Downloads>ftp ***.***.*.113
Connected to ***.***.*.113.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
User (***.***.*.113:(none)): ed
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> cd /VMLab/VirtualBoxVMs
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> bi
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> put *.zip
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Permission denied.
ftp>
```

So, what permissions is he complaining about?

Comment: If you are the owner, and can write in shell, then remote ftp with the same user should not have a problem with file permissions; so it is likely server permissions. You did not specify which FTP daemon you are using; but [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410947/permission-denied-in-ftp-even-though-im-the-owner) might be relevant? (setting `write_enable=YES` if using `vsftpd`)

Comment: Post an output with `-d` (debug) switch. + Can you upload the files using any other commandline/GUI FTP client?

Comment: @Amadan - got it. It was the write_enable in vsftpd.conf.  Post that as an 'answer' and Ill upvote it.

Comment: So it was not a programming question at all (nothing wrong with your `ftp` code/script). Please move your question to [su].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - I don't know how to move it.  I generally only live in one area of SO.

Comment: Delete and re-post there. Though now that you have an upvoted answer, you cannot delete it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, it was not a permission issue on the files; rather, the FTP server (`vsftpd`) was not allowed to write files. The relevant setting is `write_enable` in `vsftpd.conf`.